# XMLSockets in Flash Lite?

Tags: flashlite, xmlsocket

Are XMLSockets available in Flash **Lite**, and if yes in which versions, and are there differences between the regular and the lite objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know enough to tell you the exact difference(s) between XML sockets in Flash and Flash Lite, but they are definitely supported in Flash Lite versions 2.1 and later.  See the [Flash Mobile Blog](http://flashmobileblog.com/examples/) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

We're using them to send and receive text strings in both Flash 9 (PC) and Flashlite3.1 (ARM) with no code changes.  Unless there are differences in the XML parsing, you're probably good to go.